# VSTS-Agent cannot chmod

Tags: azure-devops

(target machines : RedHat 7)

I use the "Copy File" task, which works fine when using the "Overwrite" option

but when not using that option , I receive a EPERM permission denied when the vstsagent tries to chmod some files already there

there is an obvious security policy that forbids anything else but root (and sudo commands) to do chmod's on the file system

how can we adress this issue without compromising our system security ?

thanks

```
2018-06-19T13:03:59.9255736Z ##[section]Starting: Copy Files to: /data/apache/var/www/html/******
2018-06-19T13:03:59.9380638Z ==============================================================================
2018-06-19T13:03:59.9408913Z Task         : Copy Files
2018-06-19T13:03:59.9437816Z Description  : Copy files from source folder to target folder using match patterns (The match patterns will only match file paths, not folder paths)
2018-06-19T13:03:59.9466225Z Version      : 2.117.0
2018-06-19T13:03:59.9494054Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-06-19T13:03:59.9522338Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=708389)
2018-06-19T13:03:59.9550616Z ==============================================================================
2018-06-19T13:04:00.5528521Z found 7 files
2018-06-19T13:04:00.5585656Z Copying /home/saehqvsts/vstsagent2/_work/r3/a/artifact/drop/delete_files.sh to /data/apache/var/www/html/******/delete_files.sh
2018-06-19T13:04:00.5743041Z Copying /home/saehqvsts/vstsagent2/_work/r3/a/artifact/drop/images/home/blog-image01.png to /data/apache/var/www/html/******/images/home/blog-image01.png
2018-06-19T13:04:00.5773633Z Copying /home/saehqvsts/vstsagent2/_work/r3/a/artifact/drop/images/home/blog-image02.png to /data/apache/var/www/html/******/images/home/blog-image02.png
2018-06-19T13:04:00.5803794Z Copying /home/saehqvsts/vstsagent2/_work/r3/a/artifact/drop/images/home/blog-image03.png to /data/apache/var/www/html/******/images/home/blog-image03.png
2018-06-19T13:04:00.5833235Z Copying /home/saehqvsts/vstsagent2/_work/r3/a/artifact/drop/index.php to /data/apache/var/www/html/******/index.php
2018-06-19T13:04:00.5861627Z shell.js: internal error
2018-06-19T13:04:00.5890403Z Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/data/apache/var/www/html/******/index.php'
2018-06-19T13:04:00.5918532Z     at Error (native)
2018-06-19T13:04:00.5946236Z     at Object.fs.chmodSync (fs.js:1168:18)
2018-06-19T13:04:00.5975560Z     at copyFileSync (/home/saehqvsts/vstsagent2/_work/_tasks/CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c/2.117.0/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:41:6)
2018-06-19T13:04:00.6005484Z     at /home/saehqvsts/vstsagent2/_work/_tasks/CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c/2.117.0/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:198:5
2018-06-19T13:04:00.6034026Z     at Array.forEach (native)
2018-06-19T13:04:00.6063516Z     at Object._cp (/home/saehqvsts/vstsagent2/_work/_tasks/CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c/2.117.0/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:157:11)
2018-06-19T13:04:00.6094451Z     at Object.cp (/home/saehqvsts/vstsagent2/_work/_tasks/CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c/2.117.0/node_modules/shelljs/src/common.js:186:23)
2018-06-19T13:04:00.6124783Z     at Object.cp (/home/saehqvsts/vstsagent2/_work/_tasks/CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c/2.117.0/node_modules/vsts-task-lib/task.js:827:15)
2018-06-19T13:04:00.6154870Z     at matchedFiles.forEach.err (/home/saehqvsts/vstsagent2/_work/_tasks/CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c/2.117.0/copyfiles.js:119:20)
2018-06-19T13:04:00.6183521Z     at Array.forEach (native)
2018-06-19T13:04:00.6774571Z ##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name '/home/saehqvsts/vstsagent2/externals/node/bin/node', arguments '"/home/saehqvsts/vstsagent2/_work/_tasks/CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c/2.117.0/copyfiles.js"'.
2018-06-19T13:04:00.6890413Z ##[section]Finishing: Copy Files to: /data/apache/var/www/html/******
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the files are existing there, you just need to clean up the existing files in that path or using the "`Overwrite`" option to overwrite them.

Comment: if it were that simple I would not have posted a thread here :-)...I actualy need the overide option to be ticked off obviously...it's actualy weird the agent is trying a chmod on files already existing while it is not supposed to touch these files, hence the ticked off overide option

Comment: @user7082181 Unfortunately that's by design for the Copy Files task, if you want to tick off the overwrite option, then you need to write script or use command line to clean up the existing files first...

Comment: @user7082181 Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: nop...I had the option to create my own plugin but it was simpler to chmod inside the vstsagent folder, then copy the files in the destination folder....quiet silly actualy, since it bypasses the security, but at least it works